Why syft (sbom generator) can't read package.json and package-lock.json? Am I doing something wrong?
At our company, we have been using syft + dependency-track for SCA (software composition analysis). Most of the time, this works fine but when we have to check for vulnerabilities on repositories that have a package.json or package-lock.json, syft is not able to identify any packages, even though they are declared in this file. It always returns 0 packages. We are using the following command for syft:
syft <repo-name.zip> -o cyclonedx-json=sbom.json
Any ideas what might be happening?
I tried running syft on some repos and I was expecting it to return the packages that were declared in the files package.json and package-lock.json
